# How to handle enumeration of NSSet or NSArray?

Tags: objective-c

When I enumerate an `NSSet` or `NSArray` called `array` that I expect to contain objects of type `MyObject`:

```
for(MyObject *eachObject in array) {
    [eachObject methodOnMyObject];
}
```

It appears I need to perform class introspection to ensure I have the expected object every time I enumerate (or risk a crash from malformed input):

```
for(MyObject *eachObject in array) {
    if(eachObject isKindOfClass:[MyObject class]) {
        [eachObject methodOnMyObject];
    }
}
```

Or for protocols:

```
for(id<MyProtocol> *eachObject in array) {
    if(eachObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)) {
        [eachObject methodOnMyProtocol];
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to handle such cases? It seems like it would be slow to check the class type in every one of my loops.

Is the case of malformed input not something I should attempt to handle, but rather let the Exception get thrown?

Comment: You only need the checks if you don't know what sort of object is in the set/array.  If you're accepting the set/array from another component it's up to the "contract" between you whether you check the inputs or trust the other guy.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is already way too late and not fully satisfying as an answer, but if your program is in such a dynamic environment that you're not sure what objects are in the NSSet or NSArray I would use the "respondToSelector" method rather than the two you just proposed. You do, however, need to do introspection if you are not sure what objects are in the collection. so there is no better way, just a different one.

Why "respondToSelector" rather than the ones you're using? Based on your sample code, you only want to check whether the next object in the array or set responds to your methode and not returns an exception during the method call. Then later in your methode you can check if the result is not bogus and just delays the exception. Those checks, I would guess, would already be in your methode anyway.

Whether the object responds to the selector is usually in the cache of the object and therefore would not be much of a performance drain. The Apple guides also suggest to compare the object's hash, which is simpler. I don't have experience with the latter, but the "respondToSelector" never gave me a huge performance problem. Then my arrays were never that exceptionally large.